# "WITH" não é válido nesta posição para esta versão do servidor. Deploy no heroku

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

Estou fazendo um Deploy no **heroku** de um projeto pessoal desenvolvido em PHP no qual está quase concluído, porém, estou tendo esse erro com uma query do meu projeto que não está sendo executada no servidor, mas a mesma query no banco de dados do localhost ela executa normalmente, acredito que o mysql do JawsDB seja uma versão inferior da qual eu estava usando, porém, não sei como vou substituir essa query para uma versão que seja suportada e ela consiga entregar o mesmo padrão da anterior, também tentei usar o clearDB mas acontece o mesmo problema.

**O que eu quero fazer é o seguinte.** Quero que a query consiga resgatar o valor da tabela agrupados pelo dia do mês, mesmo se não tiver gasto naquele dia, ele retorna a data e o valor 0 dessa forma que está no print. Assim eu consigo colocar no gráfico os dados mensais de gasto do usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, no Workbench ele apresenta essa informação **"WITH" não é válido nesta posição para esta versão do servidor, esperando EOF,BEGIN, CACHE, CHECKSUM, COMMIT, DEALLOCATE**. Eu sinceramente não sei como substituir a query, estou iniciando no desenvolvimento web. O código mysql que desenvolvi:

```
use `jk1zzmwwn6wtsy1v`;
WITH days AS(
SELECT DATE_ADD('2020-07-01',INTERVAL rnk DAY) day
  FROM(SELECT row_number() over() -1 rnk 
  FROM information_schema.columns LIMIT 31)gerado)

SELECT
  days.day, 
  IFNULL(sum(expenses.value), 0) as amount
FROM
  days
  LEFT JOIN tb_expenses as expenses ON expenses.date = days.day 
  AND expenses.id_wallet = 0
  AND expenses.status = 1
WHERE days.day BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-07-31'
GROUP BY days.day
ORDER BY days.day
```

Comment: Verifique as versões do SGBD existentes em sua máquina e no servidor aonde está querendo instalar.

Comment: Versão do jawsdb -> 5.7.23-log (Source distribution) e está sendo compilado no linux. 

O clearDB é 5.5.62.


Já o que está sendo executado em minha máquina e usei no meu localhost foi a versão 8.0.20 (MySQL Comminity Server - GPL)